# Editing block of text on homepage with wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a little html block on my homepage that looks like the following:

```
+----------------------------+
| header text                |
+----------------------------+
| paragraph                  |
|                            |
|                            |
|                            |
+----------------------------+
| static non-changing button |
+----------------------------+
```

It is located on my sites index: `site.com/index.html`

My blog is located at: `site.com/blog/`

Is it possible to create a custom widget that edits the header and paragraph on my homepage?

Comment: With all the respect, but someone with a user reputation like yours should know better in how to compose a specific question that isn't asked before.. Did you try to google 'create widget wordpress'? http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API

Comment: Your homepage is outside of WordPress? This will be static (as in you change it and it stays that way until you change it again) or dynamic (as in changes each time someone loads it)?

Comment: Static until I change it again.